# Is ‘progressively worse’ the equivalent of ‘regressively better’?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, etymology, phrases

It’s seems like (by distribution) these two statements should be equivalent.  Are there any etymological or grammatical reasons why this should not be the case?   In this SE user’s experience, regressively better is not conventionally used, and the expressions’ meaning would not be immediately intuited by the masses as equivalent to “progressively worse.”  But are the two expressions still technically equivalent?

Comment: I would have thought regressivly better would describe a condition when things regress to an improved state, which would be like progressively worse in reverse. I have never heard the expression.

Comment: _Progressive_ here is used in the sense of _gradually increasing_, not _gradually improving_.

Comment: And so its opposite (gradually diminishing) could be regressively, correct?

Comment: **Progress** is neutral.  A chess piece can progress across the board.  A scene in a play can progress, and if it's a tragedy, things can be getting closer to the tragic ending.  **Progressively** refers to the verb's sense of incremental development or movement towards a destination or outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question. I have not encountered "*regressively better*" other than in a physical science context (and that only a couple of times in many decades).

“*progressively worse*” = “*regressively better*”?

It may be useful to consider the four possible combinations of *progress*/*regress* and *worse*/*better*.

There are at least two connotations to *progress*/*regress*. The first is a simple sense of direction or time, as in *advance*/*return*.

These directions may be qualified, so that we *progress* towards *worse* things or towards *better* things. Similarly, with *regress*: we may *regress* to *worse* or *better* things.

From this perspective, "*progress to better*" and "*regress to worse*" describe movements in opposite directions along a scale in which what is ahead is better than what is behind. This is the normal optimistic view of *progress*/*regress*: the future will be better. It leads to the second and usual connotations of *progress*/*regress*, which are *improvement*/ *deterioration*.

Similarly, "*progress to worse*" and "*regress to better*" describe movements in opposite directions along a scale in which what is ahead is worse than what is behind. It is easy to think of contemporary political viewpoints of this sort.

But *progress*/*regress* (whether for *better* or *worse*) are not equivalent, for one describes advance, the other return. They are only equivalent in an associative sense, in that they both describe consistently the changes associated with movements either way along the scale.

It is interesting to think about “*progressively worse*” = “*regressively worse*”? If this were true, it would imply that things now are better than they were or will be: no matter how we move, things get worse, so we are at the best of all – an optimum.

Similarly, “*progressively better*” = “*regressively better*”? If true this would mean things get better no matter how we move, so we are now in the worst of all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I randomly had the thought of "progressively worse" and "regressively worse" being synonymous, and a quick Google search led me to this thread.

Upon further consideration, I think "regressively worse" is just redundant.  As the previous poster points out, "progressive" can have the meaning of direction, in which case, "progressively worse" means something (health, conditions, etc) is continually moving in the direction of "worse."

Rather than say something is getting "regressively worse," the better option would be to just say that something is regressing.  For example, "her health is regressing" would mean essentially the same thing as "her health is getting progressively worse."

But, to this original question, since "regress" tends to be applied to a state of being (not as much directional, which would be more commonly "return"), I believe to say something is getting "regressively better" would be more oxymoronic than anything.